# Как запустить стороннее приложение без окна?

Tags: python

В данный момент я использую такой способ(у него большой минус в том, что окно появляется и иногда не хватает 0.5 секунды для запуска приложения):

```
boot() # Функция запуска
time.sleep(0.5) # Ждём 500ms
wnd = win32ui.FindWindow(None, 'minecraft1.12') # Находим окно
wnd.ShowWindow(SW_HIDE if wnd.IsWindowVisible() else SW_SHOW) # Скрываем окно
```

В проекте в данный момент вот такие библиотеки

```
import psutil, time, os
from pythonwin import win32ui
from win32con import SW_HIDE, SW_SHOW
```

Если можно будет сделать это без доп либ, будет вообще шикарно.

Comment: Без какого окна?

Comment: допустим у приложения есть графический интерфейс, нужно его запустить без него тоесть будет висеть как процесс.